# ggplot2: Raster plot for numeric data

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have a 2-dimensional dataset with 1,207,336 in the space [0,1]. I am aiming to visualize the density of the points. When plotting with `geom_point` I get the following

[image: geom_point]

From this, it is very difficult to tell the density. I have tried using `geom_raster()` (without any parameters), but then I get the error `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7376.8 Gb`, which is reasonable since I do *not* have 7TB of RAM.

Is there a way to transform the data before plotting, or any other way to create a heatmap in *ggplot2*?

Comment: `geom_tile`, `geom_contour`, `geom_hexbin`, `geom_density2D`. [Pick your favorite.](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/geom) But you probably want `geom_hexbin`.

Comment: If you don't have to stick with **ggplot2** necessarily, `panel.smoothScatter` from **lattice** would also be a possible solution.

Comment: Hi, Library requests are off topic to be asked on Stack Overflow. However, we can discuss about it in a chatroom. Join us [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public), if you are interested.